# How to prevent a button with transparent background colour to get the background colour of the form that instantiates it

Tags: c#, winforms, button, colors, background

I have a button with transparent background colour.
The problem is that it gets the background colour of the form that instantiates it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace CommonMethodsAndDefinitions
{
    public class TransparentButton : Button
    {
        public TransparentButton(Size buttonSize)
        {
            Size = new Size(buttonSize.Width , buttonSize.Height - 5);
            FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0; // Remove border.
            FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Transparent;
            FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.Transparent;
            FlatAppearance.CheckedBackColor = Color.Transparent;
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
            BackColor = Color.Transparent; // Set button background color to transparent.
        }
    }
}
```

In the main form:

```
Size buttonSize = new Size(75, 75);
TransparentButton customButton = new TransparentButton(buttonSize);
customButton.Location = new Point(300, 300);
Image buttonImage = Image.FromFile(_directoryContainingThePieces + "Black King.PNG");
ratioX = (float)(customButton.Size.Width - 2 * _margin) / buttonImage.Width;
ratioY = (float)(customButton.Size.Height - 2 * _margin) / buttonImage.Height;
scaleRatio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);
newWidth = (int)(buttonImage.Width * scaleRatio);
newHeight = (int)(buttonImage.Height * scaleRatio);
scaledImage = new Bitmap(pieceImage, new Size(newWidth, newHeight));
customButton.Image = scaledImage;
this.Controls.Add(customButton);
customButton.BringToFront();
```

The problem is that the button does not remain with transparent background colour but gets the background colour of the main form that instantiates it.

The button is not situated directly on the surface of the form. It is situated onto a UserControll with a different background colour and so I see that the button gets the background colour of the form.

Comment: If the button is transparent, you will of course see what's behind it, i.e. the form. Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: What result were you expecting, if not to see the color of the element that is "underneath" the button?

Comment: Winforms has no transparency. If you use a transparent color it means "paint here the backcolor of my parent". If you have other controls between your control and your parent control you want see them you might try overriding your controls paint event and start painting yourself and try to somehow repaint the things that are beneath your control that is not the parent. I'm pretty sure that is pretty complicated.

Comment: The button is not situated directly on the surface of the form. It is situated onto a UserControll with a different background colour and so I see that the button gets the background colour of the form.

Comment: The code you show states its on the main form and you do a `this.Controls.Add` therefor your button is on the form not on a user control where does the user control come into play and why don't you add the button to the user control if you want that in the background(as parent)?

Comment: @Ralf The button's parent is the form and not the user control by design. Its location is such that it falls within the surface of the already existing user control.